# How to set the DIV width value using the property list return value in ajax call from control page- MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I am trying to set the DIV width using the value return from AJAX call from the below code.
When i select the check box - the javascript should trigger and sent the ajax req.Aft the ajax code execute i am return the list of property and need to use those value to set the width of the div.

```
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var checkboxData = $(':checked').val();
                         $.ajax({
                           url: '/Home/About',
                           type: 'POST',
                           data: { id: checkboxData },
                           success: function (result) {
        //I am not sure that below code is correct but What am trying here to use the returned value to set the DivID and Divwidth
                           $(".#result.data(DivID)").css("width", #result.data(DivWidthList) + "px"); 
                            }       
                        });
                    });
                });

        </script>
        <%using (Html.BeginForm())
  { %>
       <%foreach (var cbName in (List<Hello_World_MVC.Option>)ViewData["Data"])
                  {%>
                  <div id="<%=cbName.OptionID%>" style="background-color:Blue;">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="<%=cbName.OptionID%>" value="<%=cbName.OptionID%>1" /><%=cbName.OptionName%>
                  </div>
                <%} %>  
   <%} %>
```

Model Page:

```
public class ValueProperty
{
    private List<double> divWidthList = new List<double>();
     public List<double> DivWidthList { get; set; }
    public string DivID { get; set; }
}
```

Control page:

```
    public ActionResult About(int id)
    {
        AboutModels ObjAM = new AboutModels();//model class name
        ViewData["Data"] = ObjAM.dbValue();
        ValueProperty ObjVP = new ValueProperty();
        for (int i = 20; i <= 100; i += 20)
        {
            ObjVP.DivWidthList.Add(i);//adding the value to property list
        }
        foreach (var DivValue in ObjAM.dbValue())
        {
            ObjVP.DivID = Convert.ToString(DivValue.OptionID);//insert the value for DivID
        }
        ObjAM.dbUpdate(id);
        return Json(new { data = ObjVP});//return the property value
    }
```

I need to use the returned ajax value for set the DivID and DivWidth.Here i have included my Model,Control and View page. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AJAX success callback the result variable will be the JSON serialized model that you returned in the controller action. Now the problem with your model is that it contains the ID but it also contains a list of widths (`DivWidthList`) and I don't see the relation between those two. Also here you want to set the width of a single DOM element so you should return only its width:

```
return Json(new { id = ObjVP.DivID, width = ???? });
```

and then use it like this in the success callback:

```
success: function(result) {
    var id = result.id;
    var width = result.width;
    $('#' + id).css('width', width + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin:-) Code is working fine.. But i have one more question... Is there any chance to return the muliple list of value via JSon and those value i need can use to set the width of the Div? Please  advice

Comment: @Dhana, yes you can return the list via JSON: `return Json(new { id = ObjVP.DivID, width = ????, list = ObjVP.DivWidthList });`. Then in the success callback you could loop use the `result.list` property where you could access different elements like this `result.list[0]`. The problem is that I don't understand what do you want to do with this list of widths.

Comment: @Dhana, OK, but you have a single ID and a list of Widths. Thus my confusion. If you had a list of ids and a list of corresponding widths then it would make sense but right now I don't understand your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here actually i am looking for pass the list of div Id and its Width value after the Ajax code run successfully.Got my requirment?

Comment: Sorry for your confusion.. Actually i am trying to pass the list of DivID and its corresponding Width value.